# Change background-image with CSS animation

Tags: html, css, animation, transition, viewport

How can I make this class change its background-image after 2 seconds of the div being in viewport? It's not changing for me:

```
.cover-gradient {
  background-image: none;
}

.cover-gradient:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s;
  animation: fadeMe 2s linear;
}

@keyframes fadeMe {
  0% {
    background-image: none;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(179, 49, 95, 0.5), rgba(58, 0, 117, 0.5));
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: why applying to `:after`? simply apply to the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When animating in CSS, you need to animate between two similar values.

For example, this will work:

`max-height: 0px;`
and
`max-height: 100px;`

and this will not:

`max-height: none;` and `max-height: 100px;`

However, for performance reasons, it's advisable to use `opacity` and `transform` properties when [animating in CSS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

```
.cover-gradient {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeMe 0.3s linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(179, 49, 95, 0.5), rgba(58, 0, 117, 0.5));
}

@keyframes fadeMe {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hellogareth/j3ytzq52/22